# How to make this particular table better looking?

Tags: tables, tabulary

```
  \documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{mwrep} % dwustronnie

\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}  % Marginesy (dwustronnie)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % język polski
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel, varioref}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % wstawianie zdjęć
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % jednostki SI
\usepackage{booktabs}                       % linie poziome w tab.
\usepackage{float}                          % zafiksowanie wstawek w danym miejscu
\usepackage{url}                            % adresy url
\usepackage{array, multirow}                % pomoc do tabel
\usepackage{tabulary}                       % tabele 
\usepackage{placeins}                       % FloatBarrier
\usepackage{lscape}                         % poziomy układ strony
\usepackage{chngcntr}                       % odmienne numerowanie tabel, obrazków itd.
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}             % numerowanie tabel po kolei 1,2,3,...

\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{13cm \tymax=0.4\linewidth}{CCm{2.5cm}CCC}
\toprule
Lp. & Miejscowość & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Zapotrzebowanie na wodę, $\si{m^3/\day}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Odpływ ścieków, $\si{m^3/\day}$} \\
\hphantom & \hphantom & $Q_{\text{ś}rd}$ & $Q_{maxd}$ & $Q_{\text{ś}rd}$ & $Q_{maxd}$ \\
\midrule
1.    & X1 & 57,2  & 74,4  & 54,3  & 70,7 \\
2.    & X2 & 82,5  & 107,3 & 78,4  & 101,9 \\
3.    & X3 & 47,3  & 61,5  & 44,9  & 58,4 \\
4.    & X4 & 24,2  & 31,5  & 23,0  & 29,9 \\
5.    & X5 & 211,2 & 274,7 & 200,6 & 260,9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

The outcome:
[image: 3rd column is too large I suppose]

I tried many things (like changing 3rd column from C to m{}, playing with \tymax and length etc.), but didn't get great effect.

Comment: please always post full documents not just fragments, why make people guess the needed packages?

Comment: Why don't you use the `S[table-format=3.1]` column type for the last four columns?

Comment: does this syntax really work `\begin{tabulary}{13cm \tymax=0.4\linewidth}{CCCCCC}` with the length set inside the argument?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 1) I didn't use any special command from some package in this table (just tabulary, SI, array, booktabs), so I haven't found it necessary. 2) Yes, it does work. Picture is direct compilation of the code above.

Comment: Of course it is necessary why make everyone type out a preamble to make your example work? why assume that people know booktabs (which you didn't mention) is needed. How on earth did you come up with the `{13cm \tymax=0.4\linewidth}` syntax!!! I wrote that package and I have never seen that (and whatever it does it does by accident!)

Comment: hmm I tried `\usepackage{tabulary, SI, array, booktabs}` that didn't work, so I tried  `\usepackage{tabulary, siunitx, array, booktabs}` and got `! Too many }'s.
\@endfloatbox .`  at which point I gave up, please fix your example so it produces the image shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, I've edited the 1st entry with full code that works seperately (I'm using MikTex + Texmaker btw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't parse your `tabulary` code. Here's a solution that makes use of `tabularx` as well as of the `siunitx` package to align the numbers in the four numeric columns on the decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{13cm}{@{}cc
    *{4}{S[table-format=3.1,output-decimal-marker={,}]}@{}}
\toprule
Lp. & Miejscowość 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Zapotrzebowanie na wodę, \si{m^3/\day}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Odpływ ścieków, \si{m^3/\day}} \\
& & \mC{$Q_{\text{ś}rd}$} & \mC{$Q_{maxd}$} & 
    \mC{$Q_{\text{ś}rd}$} & \mC{$Q_{maxd}$} \\
\midrule
1.    & X1 & 57,2  & 74,4  & 54,3  & 70,7 \\
2.    & X2 & 82,5  & 107,3 & 78,4  & 101,9 \\
3.    & X3 & 47,3  & 61,5  & 44,9  & 58,4 \\
4.    & X4 & 24,2  & 31,5  & 23,0  & 29,9 \\
5.    & X5 & 211,2 & 274,7 & 200,6 & 260,9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, it works, but now I don't fully understand the code ;p.

Comment: @devloon - The tabularx-code works as follows: Even though the main column type of column 3 thru 6 is of type `S`, the column types for the 4 subheader cells is of type `C`, which is a centered version of the `X` type. This is what guarantees that the overall width of the table will be 13cm.

Answer (score 6):

I would never use `tabularx` or `tabulary` for data tables such as this (even though I wrote both those packages).  They are designed to affect the total table width by controlling line breaking within the cells and (apart from the heading row) you never want line breaking in such a table. You could use `tabular*` but forcing the table to be wider than its natural width mostly just makes the table harder to read as your eye has to scan over the gaps, so I'd use `tabular`.

Also never use math italic for multi-letter identifiers so not `_{maxd}` and certainly not `\text{ś}rd` changing font mid-word.

I used Mico's example as a base as it was more realistically minimal than the one in the question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc
    *{4}{S[table-format=6.3,output-decimal-marker={,}]}
@{}}
\toprule
Lp. & Miejscowość 
& \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Zapotrzebowanie na wodę, \si{m^3/\day}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Odpływ ścieków, \si{m^3/\day}} \\
& & \mC{$Q_{\text{śrd}}$} & \mC{$Q_{\text{maxd}}$} & 
    \mC{$Q_{\text{rdś}}$} & \mC{$Q_{\text{maxd}}$} \\
\midrule
1.    & X1 & 57,2  & 74,4  & 54,3  & 70,7 \\
2.    & X2 & 82,5  & 107,3 & 78,4  & 101,9 \\
3.    & X3 & 47,3  & 61,5  & 44,9  & 58,4 \\
4.    & X4 & 24,2  & 31,5  & 23,0  & 29,9 \\
5.    & X5 & 211,2 & 274,7 & 200,6 & 260,9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find it hard to tell if the top cells in the middle columns are one line or two -- I probably can't parse it because I don't know the language.  I think centering the Q subcolumns under the top labels, like in @Mico 's answer would make it look better.

Comment: @ScottSeidman yes I suppose so, usual issue with multicolumn being wider than the things it spans, all the width goes into the second column. I may adjust it later.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I adjusted the widths a bit:-)

Comment: Thanks! I also got a q about `\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}` . It's also used in Mico's table. What does it actually do?

Comment: @devloon `\newcommand` is just latex's general command definition so `\mC` is a macro for `\multicolumn{1}{c}` just so it's shorter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah, now it's kind of obvious, didn't see it at first. One more q: what `@{}` does in `multicolumn`? And, IIUC Mico's comment, the `S` type column is special type used to generate `C` type columns in rows following `multicolumn`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  that's interesting: When I used `\textbf` on 5th row it showed up like [this](http://i.imgur.com/FWLOaUA.png)

Comment: @devloon that's not surprising, see the siunitx documentation, on formatting numbers that are being aligned by that package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55867/discussion-between-devloon-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: `5.    & X5 & 211,2 &\mC{\bfseries\tablenum[table-format=6.3,detect-all,output-decimal-marker={,}]{274,7}} & 200,6 & 260,9 \\ ` for example

Comment: I chose to make the table 13 centimeters wide simply because that's what the OP wrote in his/her code and because I assumed that there might be possibility that this particular width had some significance...

Comment: @Mico yes I know, but on principle I always suggest not using tabular[xy] on tables of numbers, I have the disadvantage of knowing all the use cases that were in my head when I thought of writing those packages, and none of them looked like this:-)

Comment: FWIW, the `tabular` environment in your answer is 351.2 pt, or 12.3 cm, wide -- only 5% less than 13 cm. Do rest assured that had I thought the table looked bad at 13 cm, I wouldn't have posted the answer I did. Instead, I would have abandoned the `tabularx`-based approach...

Comment: @Mico yes I agree that this particular table isn't really over-spread (and anyway I ended up forcing larger column separation to make the spanning headings work:-) so I wasn't positing to criticise your answer, just as I say on principle post a non tabular[xy] answer to this type of question.